# Problem : connectedness of sets

Tags: general-topology, connectedness

Are sets $$ A = \left\{ (x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 \mid -1 \leq y \leq \frac{2}{x^2 + 1} -1 \right\} $$ and 
$$B = \left\{ (x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 \mid y \geq x^2 -1 \right\} $$ connected?
I think they are connected.
I want to use the theorem that says that if we have a countable number of nonempty sets and their intersection is not an empty set and they are connected thet the set is connected. So I want to divide these sets into a countable number of nonempty connected sets whose intersection is nonempty but have no idea how to do it.

Comment: The theorem you want to use does not seem relevant here. Also, the union of countably many sets is always a set.

Comment: The theorem is true for *any* (not necessarily countable!) family of connected sets.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily make a graph and represent the two sets. Then prove that they are pathwise-connected and thus connected.

Comment: Then you should **prove** that the spaces are path connected.